# How to convert String (hh:mm) to date with current date

Tags: java, android, date, time

I' would like to calculate difference between current time and time from String (in minutes).

I've got String (from SQlite database) like this:

```
 String time1= "22:50";
```

I'm getting current date as:

```
  Date currentDate = new Date()
   long test = currentData.getTime();
```

Parsing String to date:

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
oldDate = dateFormat.parse(time1);
```

Then difference:

```
  diff = test - oldDate.getTime();
  long seconds = diff / 1000;
  long minutes = seconds / 60;
```

But main problem is caused by lack of current data information (I've only time).
I would like to have: Current data + time from String and then compare it to current date and time.

Comment: Basically you need to construct a string with the time from the database in the format `"yyyy-MM-dd "+time1+":ss"` and then parse that as a `SimpleDateFormat`. Then you could compare that to the current date/time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Java 8 time, parse the time into a `LocalTime`, apply that to a `LocalDate` with today's date, then format the result as desired.

In short:

```
// returns "2017-11-09 22:50:00"
LocalDate.now().atTime(LocalTime.parse("22:50"))
         .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

If your Android doesn't have Java 8 yet, use [ThreeTen Android Backport](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP#threeten-android-backport).

Comment: I tried that, but after gradle insert and  AndroidThreeTen.init(this); in OnCreate, still got: Call requires API level 26.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be simpler to use `LocalTime.now(desiredZoneId)` and then `ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(timeFromDb, timeNow)`? Depending on the exact requirements, of course.